# Why don’t Bruce Banner’s pants rip open when he turns into the Hulk?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers, the-incredible-hulk, hulk

Why don’t Bruce Banner’s pants rip open when he turns into the Hulk?

Comment: No i not seen but why not open his pants rip because its made by chingum so every time if he become Hulk at time his pants also become big automatically because its chingum Pants ;D

Comment: nice question :D +1

Comment: In The Avengers, didn't he wake up naked on the island he woke up on (with the older Lawn Maintenance dude helped him remember what the Hulk mighta forgot (?)

Comment: They just want to change Rating of movies or force parents to avoid movie  of hero famous amoung childers. Same like Tarzan

Comment: the age old question.  (We could also probably use a question on the Thing's thing, regarding whether that too, is made of rock--I believe Brodie  asked Stan Lee about it in the 1995 classic [Mallrats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mallrats).)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The reason is that the Hulk Comics/Cartoons/Movies are all made in focusing children, so they don't want to show Green porn.

Anyways below are Lee's funny answer on the same topic -

> **Q:** If it weren’t for the Comics Code, would the Hulk’s pants have ripped
>   off like his shirt?
>
> **Stan Lee:** I guess it probably would have. So occasionally the Code did
>   some good things.
>
> **Q:** Did you ever try to make sense of the Hulk’s magical purple pants? Why
>   did they always conveniently remain intact while the rest of his
>   clothes were ripped to shreds?
>
> **Stan Lee:** I just figured that Bruce Banner had probably been a friend
>   of Reed Richards [Mr. Fantastic from the Fantastic Four], and Reed had
>   given him some elastic trousers. There’s an explanation for
>   everything, but you may not be technically advanced enough to follow
>   me on all of this.

(Source: [comicbookmovie.com](http://www.comicbookmovie.com))

Comment: @ Ankit Sharma, great answer! Lee's answer on that is hilarious.

Answer (score 14):

They show us Bruce Banner buying some really "elastic" pants in [The Incredible Hulk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Incredible_Hulk_(film)). That's why they don't tear off I believe.

Comment: Do you have any citation for this? What part of the movie?

Comment: In The Incredible Hulk, Banner (Ed Norton) is shown buying a pair of very stretchy purple sweat pants at a South American market.

Comment: Excellent memory!  (It's too bad they can't have two accepted answers;)

Comment: @DukeZhou I even tried to find the dialogue form the film or a video but didn't succeeded. maybe I didn't tried hard.

Answer (score -1):

I always thought the Hulk was more top heavy and muscular. While his legs do become muscular, it never seemed to match the level of his upper body. It would make sense for his pants not to rip off entirely for the demographic it was intended for but there are some jokes here and there about it.

Comment: any source to back up this more top heavy theory