# Why did Susan's hair change colour?

Tags: character, monsters-vs-aliens

In Monsters VS Aliens when Susan [begins to grow in the church](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VaHpHR0U0c) her hair changes from black to white. Throughout the movie (including when she's temporally reduced back to normal size), her hair keeps its new white colour.

If the change in her hair colour was caused by the Quantonium why didn't it revert later in the movie? Why did no one appear to notice the change of colour?

Comment: A better question would be, "*How does her dress grow to fit her?*". Satin really doesn't have any give to it!

Comment: Probably but I put that down to it being a family film... otherwise it's a whole different genre! It just seemed odd they put in the effort to animate it but never mentioned it again...

Comment: @Paulster2 we already have [hulk](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11227/why-dont-bruce-banners-pants-rip-open-when-he-turns-into-the-hulk/11228#11228) question on the same topic

Comment: @AnkitSharma ... Sorry, there is no tongue-in-cheek emoticon I could throw up there. Yes, was only trying to be funny and not succeeding!

Comment: @Paulster2 i got that previously. Just saying that we already have this kind of questions :)

Comment: Ooh, good question! +1!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no in-universe answer I got but logically my thinking says that Susan's hair changed to white because her hair pigment* got permanently damaged . So when she lost her power her hair remained the same colour because the pigments was permanently lost and doesn't turn brown again.

*Human hair turns white/gray with age due to loss of hair pigments and same can be due to some radiation etc.